# What kind of music do wizards/witches listen to?

Tags: harry-potter, music

So I was laying in bed, looking at my Gryffindor poster, and then I looked on the other side of the room to my Beatles poster and a question popped into my mind. **Do wizards and witches listen to Muggle music?**

I know that there are bands from the magical world (such as the Weird Sisters), but I just thought music is so underdeveloped in that there is almost no mention of it except in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, and when mentioning the school's anthem and choir, and it kind of bothers me.

So, are Muggle bands successful in the Wizarding world?

Comment: Live / classical music. A lot of music these days requires electronics to produce, which would [fail around magic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33963/21267). So no [**Tiesto**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ti%C3%ABsto)! :(

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. But still, the weird sister play rock, and if they went to a Beatles concert, for instance, the magic concentration would probably not be high enough to actually cause any problems.

Comment: Also depends on the origins of the witch/wizard. Muggle borns will have been exposed to today's electronics (tv, radios, computers) so they might go to Hogwarts whistling some 1Direction, and all the other students punch them in the face for being such idiots! (totally unrelated to magic though)

Comment: @Mooz An actually real reason not to allow muggles in hogwarts lol.

Comment: Remember Fred & George and their radio broadcasting in Deathly Hallows? At least some Wizards and Witches would probably listen to radio at home. Maybe they played muggle music on their wizarding radio stations or maybe they simply tuned in to muggle radio?

Comment: I guess they listen to live music because *Do witches and wizards even understand record players?*

Comment: In the movie (Deathly Hollows part1), Hermione listens to a song from Nick Cave.

Comment: @MajorStackings they have radio, so there must be some way to record.

Comment: @AugustoQ I would pretty much bet that they can easily record Muggle music in a magical way and include it on wizard radio - if they want to. Whether or not they would makes me curious. Having Celestina Warbeck and The Weird Sisters for all-magical families like the Weasleys helps to create an engaging, exclusive magical world and I like JKR's creation of them, but I'd have to believe that Muggle-borns would enjoy Muggle music... a lot of it is pretty great after all! Also, they did include a pop song in one of the films in the Gryffindor Common Room.

Comment: Mostly, same kind of pop music drek that Muggles do, based on canon :(

Answer (score 7):

We can assume that they listen to Wizarding bands.
We consistently hear about The Weird Sisters, who appear in the Goblet of Fire, as well as Molly's old records of Celestina Warbeck.

The Weird Sisters appear to be a rock band, while Celestine Warbeck is confirmed to be a romance singer. I therefore assume that Wizard music is quite similar to Muggle.

Comment: What about muggle music? Do they listen to any?

Answer (score 7):

### Mostly their own

The majority of wizarding music appears to be written, performed, and composed by and for witches and wizards. Among the many examples:

- There is a band called  the Weird Sisters, which played at the Yule Ball.

  > It seemed to be fact, however, that he had booked the Weird
  >   Sisters. Exactly who or what the Weird Sisters were Harry didn’t know,
  >   never having had access to a wizard’s wireless, but he deduced from
  >   the wild excitement of those who had grown up listening to the WWN
  >   (Wizarding Wireless Network) that they were a very famous musical
  >   group.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*
- The Hobgoblins are another wizarding band, whose lead singer, Stubby Boardman, was believing by some conspiracy theorists to secretly be Sirius Black:

  > The man people believe to be Sirius Black is actually Stubby Boardman,
  >   lead singer of the popular singing group The Hobgoblins, who retired
  >   from public life after being struck in the ear by a turnip at a
  >   concert in Little Norton Church Hall nearly fifteen years ago.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*
- Celestina Warbeck is a famous musician, having released many songs, including *A Cauldron Full of Hot, Strong Love."

  > They were all supposed to be listening to a Christmas broadcast by
  >   Mrs. Weasley’s favorite singer, Celestina Warbeck, whose voice was
  >   warbling out of the large wooden wireless set. Fleur, who seemed to
  >   find Celestina very dull, was talking so loudly in the corner that a
  >   scowling Mrs. Weasley kept pointing her wand at the volume control, so
  >   that Celestina grew louder and louder. Under cover of a particularly
  >   jazzy number called “A Cauldron Full of Hot, Strong Love,” Fred and
  >   George started a game of Exploding Snap with Ginny.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

### They do know some Muggle songs

That said, there is ample evidence in the books that magical people are aware of certain Muggle music.

- The suits of armor were once enchanted to sing "Oh Come All Ye Faithful":

  > It was quite something to hear “O Come, All Ye Faithful” sung by an
  >   empty helmet that only knew half the words.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*
- Dean Thomas, under the influence of the Imperius Curse, sang "God Save the Queen." This probably means that Bartemius Crouch Jr., who was raised in the magical world, must have known it.

  > Dean Thomas hopped three times around the room, singing the national
  >   anthem.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

These songs seem to be more in the category of "classics," though, rather than contemporary popular music.